Dynamic positioning for labels of small portions in pie
I would like to handle the issue of label overlaping in matplotlib while I am plotting pie chart
My question is: how can I dynamically repoistion the label such that they do not overlap?
I also want to use lines to link the labels to the slices.
like this:
enter image description here
Sample code:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [("a001", 0.0001),
        ("a002", 0.0002),
        ("a003", 0.0004),
        ("a004", 0.0008),
        ("a005", 0.0016),
        ("a006", 0.0032),
        ("a007", 0.0064),
        ("a008", 0.0128),
        ("a009", 0.0256),
        ("a010", 0.0512),
        ("a011", 0.1024),
        ("a012", 0.2048),
        ("a013", 0.4096),
        ("a014", 0.1809)]

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
slices = [i[1] for i in data]
labels = [i[0] for i in data]
plt.pie(slices, labels=labels)
plt.title("Title")
plt.show()

The undesired result is like:
enter image description here
Thanks a lot in advance!
labels automatically repositioned to avoid overlapping

Have you read the documentation?
